# Permission to a single list item by particular person

Tags: list, permissions, custom, item

I've created an Employee List and I would like to make a webpart on the main employees page so that he or she can access/display their own list item - employee item, not the rest of the list.

I played a bit with permissions, but I can't get it working for some reason.

The list must be accessible to managers etc, but only one item can be accessible by that particular staff member. So if the staff goes to this Employees List, he can only see his list item.

Now, I've tried adding web part/content query to display the logged in username Name only. It display a link to the list item, but if I don't give access to this list, the person cannot read that one item. It's blocked.

If the list is only accessible to certain people, not the actual employee I'm talking about, adding permission to that one list item doesn't seem to work either. The person cannot access the page.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How many items do you have in the list?

Comment: At the moment only a few, but eventually there will be over 250 staff added.

Answer (score 1):

Mihail's solution works, but if you really want to make it yourself very easy, I would suggest just giving contributors permission to edit their own items and make all others invisible. You can do that by doing the following:

1. Go to the advanced settings of your list, go to item level permissions and select "Read items that were created by user" + "Create items and edit items that were created by the user" like you can see here:
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtnLO.png
2. For people who want to see everything, put them in a group that have the permission level with the cancel check in base permission

Comment: Hey Christoffel, thanks for bringing this option to my attention. Unfortunately, the items can only be created by HR team. Your solution works for creators, but not for employees.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to propose a solution that assumes that your list has a **person** field named **Employee** and that you have a group called **Managers**.

#### What you need:

1. A list view called **My Employee Info** that is filtered to display only the items where the **Employee** is equal to **[Me]**.
2. A list workflow that sets unique permissions for each item. The workflow should provide permissions only to the **Managers** group and the person specified in the **Employee** field. The workflow can run on item creation or item update.
3. On the site page, just add your employee list as a web part and modify the web part to display the **My Employee Info** list view created earlier.
4. All users should have read access to the list.

If this solution does not work for you, please say why and I will try to improve it based on your needs.

Comment: Hi Mihail, I have done something like this customising a view in a web part. I haven't tried workflow yet. The employee had access to his own item - when closed, it went back to the main page. The employee did have access to the list, but when clicked on somebody else, access was denied. Unfortunately, the employee can see the entire list with details. I could hide links to the Employee List, but it's not ideal. cntd.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to use workflows. I'm using Office 365, all activated in site settings, but it's abit confusing :o

Comment: I have not developed any workflows for Office 365, but from what I am reading on the Internet, the process is the same as for SharePoint on-premises. So, you need SharePoint Designer 2013 to write workflows. Here is an article to get you started: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj554671.aspx

Comment: Hey, I now understand workflows, however I'm not sure how to set permissions. As I was googling I found this: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/e2e59b58-8623-472b-8314-f2967e5271e9/sharepoint-2013-workflow-update-list-item-permissions-in-workflow?forum=sharepointgeneral is this still the case to get set permissions in SharePoint (2013)?

Comment: Yes, for SharePoint on-premises this is the case. Assuming that the farm is configured with a Workflow Manager Farm, then you can create 2 types of workflows: 2010 and 2013. 2013 workflow provide new functionality via the Workflow Manager Farm, while 2010 workflows provide the old SP workflow functionalities: e.g. setting item permissions. I am not however aware if you can create 2010 workflows for Office 365. Normally, when you create a new workflow using SharePoint Designer, it should ask you which workflow platform you want to use: 2010 or 2013.

Comment: Hi, I tried creating a workflow in SPD 2013 using SPD 2010 template, but permission actions are not available. I'm currently playing with View settings etc. Trying to block the access to the list for non admin users. They can access the list via site contents. Any idea how to hide it for non admins?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on Sharepoint online I would expect that you would use the ootb integration with Delve.
Which requirements makes that approach a No go.?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar thing on share point & I solved thru following approach

1. At list level only permissions to Owner Group only
2. Item Level permission Read All item & create edit All items (as per @Mihali said)
3. Power Automate Runs to disctribute Limited Access to Item Level to individual as per application requirement.

It's working fine...